# Starling vs Display List for book mobile app

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe, starling-framework

I am wondering what would be a better solution for a mobile adobe air app that has a lot of text and a lot of big images (~500). I couldnt just put everything on the gpu at the beginning  so i would constantly have to refresh gpu content. Which would result in anoying loading screens. On the other hand, would display list be able to bring smooth scrolling experience? Is starling really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, GPU can handle huge data in only one draw call, only when it comes to drawing the same context. and context includes textures, which would be images in your app. Because bitmap dimension is limited to 2048x2048 for textures, you must consider resizing them if they're too big. Also uploading bitmaps to textures will consume significant amount of time.

Plus, in Adobe Air for mobile, there will be severe limitations on true-type font renderings on stage3D, and readability will be a another headache in case of bitmap fonts, as MipMaps will only use bilinear method for scaling.

If you are going to display texts embedded true-type fonts for readability, and render big(how much, is quite a issue here) images, you will have to deal with some problems with those things.

well, refreshing gpu content is not the issue, at least in my opinion. uploading data to gpu takes some time, right, but it will be insignificant compared to decompressing, which is inevitable in both stage and stage3D.

Comment: so you would say display list is probably a better way to go?

Comment: It depends on situation. if you want to apply 3D transformations, or apply other matrix transformations dynamically on huge bitmap images, you should consider Stage3D. otherwise, I would recommend conventional display list for "Book-Reader-Style" apps.